# Data Ingestion Using Big query's python client exceeds cloud functions maximum limit

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to auto-ingest data from gcs into bigquery using a bucket triggered cloud function.the file types are gzipped json files which can have a maximum size of 2gb.the cloud function works fine with small files.however it tends to timeout when i give it large files that range from 1 to 2 gbs.is there a way to further optimize my function here is the code below:

```
def bigquery_job_trigger(data, context):
    
    # Set up our GCS, and BigQuery clients
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    client = bigquery.Client()

    file_data = data
    file_name = file_data["name"]
    
    
    
    table_id = 'BqJsonIngest'
    bucket_name = file_data["bucket"]
    dataset_id = 'dataDelivery'

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.autodetect = True

    blob = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name).get_blob(file_name)
    file = blob.open("rb")
    client.load_table_from_file(
            file,
            table_ref,
            location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
            job_config=job_config,
    )
```

Comment: Why do you read the file in your Cloud Functions? Do you want to transform it? If not, Shollyman answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If the file's already in GCS, there's no need to open the blob inside your function (or the need to do so is not apparently from the snippet provided).

See `client.load_table_from_uri`, or just checkout one of the existing code samples like https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv#bigquery_load_table_gcs_csv-python

Comment: Is there someway i could make bigquery notify me if the job has finished successfully  because running `job.result` after `load_table_from_uri` makes my function time out because its the job takes 16 min to complete.also in this case if i have multiple files is it better to load them all at once in one job using a wild card or should i load each file separetly ?

Comment: `job.result` is a "wait until done" blocking call.  You can call `job.done` with some loop construct to poll it periodically rather than blocking.  As far as your other question generally it's better to load multiple files in a single job given the choice; they get committed to table storage as an atomic unit.